# Problem with asynchronous function type Promise<faceProductList[] | string>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why do I get an error when using the type Promise . to asynchronous functions.
err
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

```
import { faceProductList } from "../../Type/Interface";

class Server {
  private url: string = "https://...../";

  public async request(id: string): Promise<object | string> {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${this.url}${id}`);
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw Error("Page Not Found 404");
      }
      const resArr: object = await res.json();
      return resArr;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.message;
    }
  }

  public async handler(
    pathname: string,
    valueSearch: string
  ): Promise<faceProductList[] | string> {
    try {
      const prodObj = await this.request(pathname);
      if (typeof prodObj === "string") {
        throw Error(prodObj);
      } else if (valueSearch) {
        return Object.values(prodObj)
          .flat()
          .filter(({ title }) => title.includes(valueSearch));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `prodObj` is not of type `string` and `valueSearch` is falsy (empty string for example) - function returns `undefined` implicitly. You should decide what to do (to return) in this case.

```
if (typeof prodObj === "string") {
    throw Error(prodObj);
} else if (valueSearch) {
    return Object.values(prodObj)
        .flat()
        .filter(({ title }) => title.includes(valueSearch));
}
// undefined returned here implicitly
```

> A function without a return statement will return a default value. In the case of a constructor called with the `new` keyword, the default value is the value of its `this` parameter. For all other functions, the default return value is `undefined`.